# Want to add new own button in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a new plugin for wordpress.
At a very high level my requirement is

1 Add a custom button ( let's call it MyButton) in tinyMCE editor toolbar.
 2 Click on the button should open a new popup div/window.

I tried this code,But unable to add my custom button.

```
function add_more_buttons($buttons) {
  $buttons[] = 'hr';
  $buttons[] = 'del';
  $buttons[] = 'cut';
  $buttons[] = 'sup';
  $buttons[] = 'MyButton'; // Want to add my custom button
 return $buttons;
}
add_filter("mce_buttons_2", "add_more_buttons");
```

Anyone having any idea???

Answer (score 1):

To add a button to TinyMCE, you must use a tinyMCE plugin.

```
function add_youtube_button() {
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_youtube_tinymce_plugin');
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_youtube_button');
   }
}

add_action('init', 'add_youtube_button');

function register_youtube_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "|", "brettsyoutube");
   return $buttons;
}

function add_youtube_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
   $plugin_array['brettsyoutube'] = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/custom/editor_plugin.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}
```

Full exemple can be found [here](http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button). There's also a button skeleton available to download (including js and php files)